# On screen enemy indicating arrow

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics

I am working on indicating on screen arrow to point towards the enemy. I have a environment which consist of a player and three enemy placed at different position on the environment.I need an arrow indicating the enemy,so that the player can move towards the enemy in the environment.

How can I do this?Can anybody please help me out.

I have got a script on searching.

```
public Texture2D icon; //The icon. Preferably an arrow pointing upwards.
public float iconSize = 50f;
[HideInInspector]
public GUIStyle gooey; //GUIStyle to make the box around the icon invisible. Public so that everything has the default stats.
Vector2 indRange;
float scaleRes = Screen.width / 500; //The width of the screen divided by 500. Will make the GUI automatically
//scale with varying resolutions.
Camera cam;
bool visible = false; //Whether or not the object is visible in the camera.

void Start () {
    visible = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().isVisible;

    cam = Camera.main; //Don't use Camera.main in a looping method, its very slow, as Camera.main actually
    //does a GameObject.Find for an object tagged with MainCamera.

    indRange.x = Screen.width - (Screen.width / 6);
    indRange.y = Screen.height - (Screen.height / 7);
    indRange /= 2f;

    gooey.normal.textColor = new Vector4 (0, 0, 0, 0); //Makes the box around the icon invisible.
    visible=false;
}

void OnGUI () {
    if (visible) {
        Vector3 dir = transform.position - cam.transform.position;
        dir = Vector3.Normalize (dir);
        dir.y *= -1f;

        Vector2 indPos = new Vector2 (indRange.x * dir.x, indRange.y * dir.y);
        indPos = new Vector2 ((Screen.width / 2) + indPos.x,
            (Screen.height / 2) + indPos.y);

        Vector3 pdir = transform.position - cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(indPos.x, indPos.y,
            transform.position.z));
        pdir = Vector3.Normalize(pdir);

        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(pdir.x, pdir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(angle, indPos); //Rotates the GUI. Only rotates GUI drawn after the rotate is called, not before.
        GUI.Box (new Rect (indPos.x, indPos.y, scaleRes * iconSize, scaleRes * iconSize), icon,gooey);
        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(0, indPos); //Rotates GUI back to the default so that GUI drawn after is not rotated.
    }
}

void OnBecameInvisible() {
    visible = false;
}
//Turns off the indicator if object is onscreen.
void OnBecameVisible() {
    visible = true;
}
```

}

The problem is start when I play the scene the arrow is seen at the start but its  get invisible soon

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best option but what I would do is:

- initialize an image arrow.png loaded in a variable
- get currently selected enemy position x,y
- get your position x2,y2
- get the angle angle1 between you and the enemy with Vector2.Angle method
- draw your arrow at (x+x2)/2 , (y+y2)/2 rotated with the angle1 you got

I do not know Unity and it is possible that there is a class which already cover this.

Comment: When you log/println the values for indPos.x and .y, they are always in the camera view box ? Also, could you println when the method isBecameInvisible is called? It is possible that the event triggering this method is not working properly.

Comment: I have a issue.When I take the build of the project,its arrow mark is not getting appeared on the instead.When we move the player the arrow get appeared?what will be the reason

Comment: Could you just log the values of visible from start to the end ?

Comment: yes Will log the value

Comment: after changing the value of visible to  "public bool visible = false;" and OnGUI() { if(!visible) to if(visible)

Comment: I do not know if your previous comment is complete or if the end is missing. Just let us know what the log tells you and if it helps you in the troubleshooting of your error